# Polymorphic object update in OCaml

Tags: object, polymorphism, ocaml

I want to achieve a system, where objects are polymorphic over their field's contents and that content can be changed. I.e. an object offers a generic way to exchange field `f` with value `a` of type `a_t` with a value `b` of type `b_t` for every field `f`.

A first attempt would be something like this:

```
class ['a] not_working (a : 'a) = object 
  val _a = a
  method field_a = _a
  method modify_a new_a = {< _a = new_a >}
end
```

This is not polymorphic enough, as the type of `not_working` is:

```
class ['a] not_working : 'a -> object ('b) val _a : 'a method field_a : 'a method modify_a : 'a -> 'b end
```

i.e. the modification yields an object of the same type.

My workaround is the following:

```
class ['fields_t] the_class (fields : 'fields_t) = object

  method field_a = fields#field_a

  method field_b = fields#field_b

end

let modify_field_a instance new_a = new the_class (object method field_a = new_a ; method field_b = instance#field_b end)

let modify_field_b instance new_b = new the_class (object method field_a = instance#field_a ; method field_b = new_b end)

let instance = new the_class (object method field_a = 1 ; method field_b = "foo" end)

let mod_instance = modify_field_a instance "1"
```

I generate a modification function for every field in the_class and this modification function updates this field and copies all others. This is quite noisy.

Is there a way to use the object copy operator or a comparable construct in a similar manner to reduce the boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can do what you're after with objects, as I think that would involve a non-regular recursive type:

```
type 'a foo = < modify: 'b. 'b -> 'b foo >
```

Note the error message if you try to define that type:

```
Characters 4-42:
  type 'a foo = < modify: 'b. 'b -> 'b foo >;;
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error: In the definition of foo, type 'b foo should be 'a foo
```

You might have better luck using records (or first-class modules):

```
# type ('a, 'b) foo = { a: 'a; b: 'b };;
type ('a, 'b) foo = { a : 'a; b : 'b; }

# let new_foo a b = {a; b};;
val new_foo : 'a -> 'b -> ('a, 'b) foo = <fun>

# let modify_a r new_a = { r with a = new_a };;
val modify_a : ('a, 'b) foo -> 'c -> ('c, 'b) foo = <fun>

# let modify_b r new_b = { r with b = new_b };;
val modify_b : ('a, 'b) foo -> 'c -> ('a, 'c) foo = <fun>
```

Comment: "Non regular recursive type". Interesting. If this is indeed the problem, then OCaml does not support the `... with ...` syntax on objects because its type system cannot assign a type to the function. And this because OCaml does not support row-type variables, i.e.:

`<a : 'a; 'b> -> 'c -> <a : 'c; 'b>` cannot be typed (I think it was possible in the original row-polymorphism paper)

Comment: It's not really related to OCaml's lack of support for first-class row variables. It is because non-regular type recursion must go through a data constructor. Records are a data constructor, where as objects are structural types. For a similar example 
`type 'a btree =
  Nil of 'a
| Succ of ('a * 'a) btree`
 is fine but 
``type 'a btree =
[ `Nil of 'a
| `Succ of ('a * 'a) btree ]``
 is not allowed, because polymorphic variants are structural,